# When did Stack Overflow get comments?

Tags: support, review-queues, comments

Someone must have came upon an ancient answer of mine in the review queue or something and they told me that my answer was not helpful and it should have been a comment.

Well, I'm pretty sure that answer predated the ability to leave comments, but I can't say for sure.  I would have laughed it off, but that comment had an upvote of all things (which means two people think I'm a slovenly answerer).  So, I did the right thing and made my crummy answer a legit answer and told the person commenting on my post to get a life.

Is there a list of when certain (Stack Overflow only) features came online I can use to point out to those accusing me, one of the most ancient of users, of the crime of leaving a comment as an answer of my innocence?

Comment: for a bit of related history,  see [Comments: Top n Shown](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/comments-top-n-shown/) _"We originally implemented comments as almost an afterthought, with virtually no emphasis placed on them in favor of our core Question and Answer mission..."_

Comment: Rather than being rude ("told the person commenting on my post to get a life"), it would have been better to thank them for their efforts  to try and improve the quality here, and for the reminder that gave you the opportunity to convert your "crummy answer" (your own words) into a "legit answer".

Comment: @ken txk I'll try to keep that in mins next time

Comment: There might be a decent argument for not pushing very old posts into review queues to start with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The oldest *by creation date* is:

```
2008-08-01 13:09:18.970
```

The oldest *by database id* is:

```
2008-09-06 08:07:10.730
```

The disparity could be from posts converted to comments (posts converted to comments retain the post's creation-date)

Comment: Thanks! That goes a long way to clearing up [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/291129/1765) vendetta.  I thought for a minute that he was right when I looked the dates on the other comments.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be proving your point. Your answer was posted on 2008-11-14; another answer on the same question posted on 2008-10-09 has comments posted that day. That suggests that it *would* have been possible for you to post a comment instead of an answer in November 2008.

Comment: @AndrewMedico that also depends on how much rep the OP had on that day

Comment: @MarcGravell It was acceptable to post an comment as an answer if you didn't have the reputation to comment back then?

Comment: @ross, that's the main point, no one cared that much back then. Being critiqued six years later  then having my post deleted after actually fixing it is craziness!

Comment: @PeterTurner I think maybe you're taking the critique a little too personally. Remember it was made today, when people do care. If the person making the comment presumed that you should've known better back in November 2008 then maybe he made a mistake. But that doesn't mean the claim that your answer should be a comment is invalid. I don't know why your answer was subsequently deleted, so I won't comment on that. You might need to take that up as a separate question.

Comment: @ross well it appears to have escaped being converted into a comment when other posts apparently were, that's what I was asking about concerning the dates.  I have no way of knowing whether the comments on the other posts in that answer were real comments or converted comments. I think it would only be reasonable for me to post a comment if there were other comments. Plus back then comments were capped at quite a bit less than nowadays as I recall fondly................

Answer (score 8):

Comments did exist when you posted that answer (on 2008-11-14), and you did have the ability to post comments at the time. [Your first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88211/how-do-you-convert-your-office-to-build-automation#comment12175_88211) was posted on 2008-09-18.

Comment: Umm, I think this should have been posted as a comment...

Comment: @PeterTurner: No, it answers your question about whether you can point to comments having been unavailable to you in such cases.  **No, you can't.**